# Are there any good modern typescript examples for resolvejs?

Tags: typescript, resolvejs

I noticed that most of the docs are quite old, refereing a very old version of react.

I would like to tinker with Resolve and Typescript and potentially write a blog post about it but im wary of following an old way of using the lib.

Does anyone have any good modern Typescript examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment all examples are in JS, but TS is supported, here is the starting point:

```
npx create-resolve-app you-app-name -e hello-world-typescript
```

We do have some internal apps being developed with TS, so feel free to ask more specific questions.

We plan to add a dedicated TypeScript section to the documentation.

Regarding old React - yes, some examples are old. We have added [React Hooks](https://reimagined.github.io/resolve/docs/frontend#resolve-react-hooks-library) support last year, so those examples are most fresh.

Comment: Hmm I would love to see something that actually uses typescript. The hello-world-typescript example is basically just JS but with the files renamed to `.ts` or `.tsx` nothing is typed. 

Would love to see actual real examples of strongly typed code :)

Comment: Next release (should be out this week) will contain more type definitions for reSolve api. We don't have immediate plans to create a separate example in TypeScript, because it would be almost the same as JS, just with types. 
We could just rewrite one example in TS and compile it to JS for those who don't know TS. But i'm not sure how good JS result would look.

Comment: Awesome, looking forward to seeing the type defs. I really think you should convert something more substantial to TS, perhaps the hacker-news example. TS is a major player in the web world these days particularly when you are talking about large complex codebases like Resolve might lead to. I think if you can fully-type the hacker-news example it would let you hash out any edgecases in the typing too. I could have a crack at it with the new types if you arent interested?

Comment: We've released new version of the framework with reworked examples. Every example now originally written in TypeScript and automatically converted to JavaScript. You can use create-resolve-app tool with --typescript flag or browse manually in repository.